# Windows 7: Alt-tab not activating window sufficiently to indicate "I've seen this" (Maybe just in Windows Live?)

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger, alt-tab

Many applications when run in Windows 7 change the application's taskbar alerts to indicate changed state - but once you've clicked the window, they return to normal.  The primary place I see this is Windows Live Messenger - when you receive a message, a little speech bubble appears on the taskbar icon; once you've clicked the window with the message, the speech bubble disappears.

However, I'm pretty keyboard oriented.  And alt-tabbing to the chat window doesn't seem to be sufficient to tell the system to stop telling me.

Is there any way to fix this?  Because I haven't got any other applications that make much use of the functionality, I'm unclear on whether it's the fault of Windows or Messenger...

Comment: As a point of interest, I've found something of a workaround; if you have multiple chats open, you can alt-tab to any other chat window then ctrl-tab to the window in question; that seems to be enough to activate the change.  It's more awkward than it needs to be, though...

Comment: I've just realised the above trick works if there's only the one as well: ctl-tab while in the window and it'll deactivate the "unread" marker.